# Insert using UDTs and returning the identity values

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I wish to insert many rows of data into a table in SqlServer and was planning on using table valued parameters (for its performance when inserting 100s of rows). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

The Msdn article shows me how to insert many rows from a C# application as well as the stored procedure to do this.

But what I am not sure of is, as to how to return the identity values for all the rows that I inserted, from the stored procedure back to the C# app? (I cannot update the UDT as it is readonly within the stored procedure)

Can I create a separate UDT to return the array of inserted identity values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try out the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause - tbh, that MSDN reference gives you everything you need with examples so I won't paraphrase! You can just OUTPUT the required fields (i.e. the IDENTITY values & any  other relevant info) back as a resultset..